# Richfaces ModalPanel - title background image

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I need to use an image as background in a modalPanel title.
I'm using JSF + Richfaces.

Is is possible?

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering what is the problem with my question. I did research, but I think I haven't used the correct keywords.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote. By the way, maybe if you use firebug you could detect the css style applied to the background, extend it and add a background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible by inserting a header facet into the modal panel with the content that you wish to appear in the panel.

```
<f:facet name="header">
   <div style="background: url("/bla/foo.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #F36D21;" />
</f:facet>
```

On the inside you can just declare a div with a repeating background image as a backdrop to other content in your facet header.

Comment: Tks, I'm gonna test this now.